# Reading text from image in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to scrap text from image element, as in the picture:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJuxk.jpg)

I did everything else, but

```
Salzufer 16
10587 Berlin
```

Is in the shape of an image?

I use Selenium webdriver and need to scrape data like Address,Contact,Branch of economic activity..

Comment: this seems more like `OCR` than web scraping.

Comment: it seems like text is encrypted and JavaScript decrypt it on run-time.  However, it should not happen with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the html (search for the address) you'll see, that the address actually appears in a javascript code, that generates a google map.

You could exploit this using a regular expression.

Assuming that you've already coded the part where you perform the search and now just need to extract the address. Your selenium object is named driver. Then it would be something like this:

```
import re
page_source = driver.page_source
add_pattern = '{address: \"(.*?)\"}'
address = re.search(page_source, add_pattern).group(1)
print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the text that you are looking for is embedded in the "text" argument of the textRender.aspx file. You may consider to reverse engineer it.

Otherwise for more general purpose OCR you can use Google Vision APIs https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: For the first part of the answer, can you be more specific? What should I do?